# Tabulate top n most repeated values including others

Tags: r

I have created a table that includes a list of 1000 songs organized by gender,theme, etc. I want to know how many years are repeated and how many are in an other category. I have tried:

```
sort(summary(as.factor(canciones$YEAR)), decreasing=T)[1:3]
```

And the output is:

```
1968 1966 1979 
  39   37   34
```

But I want it to be

```
1968 1966 1979 Others
  39   37   34    950
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible and generalizable example of this question so that we (and future readers) can recreate your problem?

Comment: Why would you not use `table` here?

Answer (score 9):

Here are some sample data.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(10, 500, TRUE)
```

We can run the entire summary, subset the first three, then calculate the remaining values as "Others" and tack it on the end.  Additionally, I think you can just use `table()` instead of `summary(factor())` since `summary.factor()` does this under the hood anyway.

```
xx <- sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
c(xx[1:3], Others = sum(xx[-(1:3)]))
#     5      2      4 Others 
#    64     61     57    318
```

Note: It may or may not be faster to use `Others = length(x) - sum(xx[1:3])`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using a parameter called maxsum

```
plot_data <- sort(summary(as.factor(canciones$YEAR),maxsum=3), decreasing=T)[1:3]
```